# Как отследить на нажатие мимо AlertDialog или закрытие без действия

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Мне важно получить решение пользователя в `AlertDialog`, но если человек нажмет мимо поля `AlertDialog` просто закрывается.

Как я могу отследить это (закрытие без ответа) или сразу перезапустить `AlertDialog`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `setOnDismissListener`

Comment: Также можно заблокировать закрытие диалога иными способами, кроме нажатия по кнопкам: [`setCancelable(false)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCancelable(false)) и [`setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Блокировка нажатий мимо setCancelable(false) и setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)